# Device not working with Firebase Authentication Phone Number

Tags: ios, iphone, firebase, firebase-authentication

I have an iPhone that I'm trying to use with firebase authentication using phone numbers.

The project works and the emulator + device (without sim card) works using that phone number of the device that doesn't work (receives sms). But when I try to "login" on the device (with sim) I keep getting `nil` from `verifyPhoneNumber`. Is there something I'm missing that has to be active on the device?

This is the code that I'm trying to call with the text field as +1**********, along with `FirebaseApp.configure()` in the AppDelegate

```
PhoneAuthProvider.provider().verifyPhoneNumber(phoneTextField.text!, uiDelegate: nil) { (veri, error) in
    if error != nil {
        print(veri)
    } else {
        print(error)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

There is likely an error, but it's not surfacing because the `if` statement is backwards. Instead, it should be

```
PhoneAuthProvider.provider().verifyPhoneNumber(phoneTextField.text!, uiDelegate: nil) { (veri, error) in
    if error != nil {
        print(error)
    } else {
        print(veri)
    }
}
```

This will then print `error` instead of `veri`. It's likely printing `nil` because `veri` has no value if there's an error.